# How can I deal with cyclic composition in C++?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to create a cyclic composition in C++ but I'm dealing with declaration problems. How could I solve them?

This is an example, class A contains a vector of B objects, but class B needs A to be declared first because it's needed in its constructor:

```
class A {
private:
    std::vector<B> sons;
public:
    void create_son() {
        B obj(this);
        sons.push_back(obj);
        obj.some_method();
    }
};

class B {
private:
    A* parent;
public:
    B (A* _parent) { parent = _parent; }
    void some_method() {}
};
```

Comment: You don't a complete type A to use pointers, it is enough with a (forward) declaration `class A;`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `class A`, you use object of `class B`, so the complete definition of `class B` is needed. To solve this, put `class B` definition above `class A`. At the same time, in `class B` you work only with pointer to A, so you don't need the complete definition of `class A`: declaration is enough there.

So, add forward declaration of `class A` above `class B` definition.

```
class A;

class B {
private:
    A* parent;
public:
    B (A* _parent) { parent = _parent; }
    void some_method() {}
};

class A {
private:
    std::vector<B> sons;
public:
    void create_son() {
        B obj(this);
        sons.push_back(obj);
        obj.some_method();
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can forward declare pointer types:

```
class A;   // sufficient to fully determine B

class B {
private:
    A* parent;
public:
    B (A* _parent) { parent = _parent; }
    void some_method() {}
};

// now we have B defined, we can define A
class A {
private:
    std::vector<B> sons;
public:
    void create_son() {
        B obj(this);
        sons.push_back(obj);
        obj.some_method();
    }
};
```